# Email notifications for skype messages

Tags: skype

I don't like to run skype all the time anymore. Is there any way to get chat notifications sent to my email account without Linux server?

Comment: Why did you put tags that are unrelated to skype?

Comment: What version of Skype? Desktop? Mobile?